# How can I calculate the difference between two columns of a table visual in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi

[image: My table visual in Power BI]

I have these columns in Power BI, how can I calculate the difference between 2022 Q2 and 2022 Q1, and then add that difference as another column in the table (ideally as a percentage)?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a measure.  There's a Quick Measure for that particular calculation:

[image]

Creates a measure like

```
SalesAmount QoQ% = 
IF(
    ISFILTERED('FactInternetSales'[OrderDate]),
    ERROR("Time intelligence quick measures can only be grouped or filtered by the Power BI-provided date hierarchy or primary date column."),
    VAR __PREV_QUARTER =
        CALCULATE(
            SUM('FactInternetSales'[SalesAmount]),
            DATEADD('FactInternetSales'[OrderDate].[Date], -1, QUARTER)
        )
    RETURN
        DIVIDE(
            SUM('FactInternetSales'[SalesAmount]) - __PREV_QUARTER,
            __PREV_QUARTER
        )
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I think that will work for comparing 2022 Q2 with 2022 Q1, but how would I compare 2022 Q2  with 2021 Q2 for example?

Comment: There's a quick measure for Year-over-Year change too.

Answer (score 0):

you should create as many measures as you like in order to calculate all the time intelligence calculations that you need. Once you have made then, you can transform those values into % from the Format Tab afther choosing the DAX measure that you want to format